# Как запустить Node.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cryptojs

В общем установил crypto-js ,react. 
Но затем захожу на http://site/public/index.html и ничего не происходит, что нужно сделать?

============

при запуске

> npm run test

```
No tests found related to files changed since last commit.
Press `a` to run all tests, or run Jest with `--watchAll`.

Watch Usage
 › Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
 › Press t to filter by a test name regex pattern.
 › Press q to quit watch mode.
 › Press Enter to trigger a test run.
```

Comment: Как минимум сервер запустить. Незнаю как в react, есть ли свой дев, но попробуйте `npm run test`

Comment: localhost:3000 или какой там у вас

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm run test` запустит `unit-test`. Видимо, скрипт который вы запускаете создан на основе `create-react-app`. Попробуйте выполнить `npm start`, приложение будет запущено на локальном хосте, вероятнее всего на 3000 порту, т.е. чтобы увидеть ваше приложение - после запуска перейдите в браузере по ссылке http://localhost:3000